# User Login using API

Tags: api, ios4, authentication, api-eveonline

I'm currently trying to create a simple application for my own use (I'm trying to learn iPhone Programming) and I want to know how you create a login page which will log a user in and store/keep them logged in via an API.

I don't know where to begin on storing information/cached info etc.

I want to use the current API that is all in XML from Eveonline here: http://wiki.eve-id.net/APIv2_Page_Index

I can't find any examples online for Xcode to learn/work off, nor can I find any code snippets that would somewhat explain the process.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API I would use something like NSURLRequest as it is a straight forward HTTP login with authentication by token.

[Here is an example](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSURLRequest)